# German characters in Drupal getting cut off (possibly due to mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have a drupal page in German. It was written somewhere else but when I paste it into a drupal page and save, only half or quarter of the text is saved. For some reason, the rest of the text does not get saved in the database and only a quarter of the text shows up when viewed after a save. So, basically it is cut off. Is this a database issue or a drupal issue?

Comment: sounds like a charset problem with you database, if ther german umlauts cut your text string.

Comment: Post the text into a file first, then make sure that file has the correct charset.  Use a good text editor or a good IDE to check the char encoding.  Its not a magic bullet but I find this often works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone that is still interested. Copy all your German text, put it in Microsoft Word, go to the Review tab and click on Set Language, and choose English. Paste it back into your drupal textbox and submit!